# Get Hbase region size via API

Tags: hadoop, hbase

I am trying to write a balancer tool for Hbase which could balance regions across regionServers for a table by region count and/or region size (sum of storeFile sizes). I could not find any Hbase API class which returns the regions size or related info. I have already checked a few of the classes which could be used to get other table/region info, e.g. org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HTable and HBaseAdmin.

I am thinking, another way this could be implemented is by using one of the Hadoop classes which returns the size of the directories in the fileSystem, for e.g. org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem lists the files under a particular HDFS path.

Any suggestions ?

Answer (score 7):

I use this to do managed splits of regions, but, you could leverage it to load-balance on your own.  I also load-balance myself to spread the regions ( of a given table ) evenly across our nodes so that MR jobs are evenly distributed.

Perhaps the code-snippet below is useful?

```
final HBaseAdmin admin = new HBaseAdmin(conf);
final ClusterStatus clusterStatus = admin.getClusterStatus();

for (ServerName serverName : clusterStatus.getServers()) {
  final HServerLoad serverLoad = clusterStatus.getLoad(serverName);

  for (Map.Entry<byte[], HServerLoad.RegionLoad> entry : serverLoad.getRegionsLoad().entrySet()) {
    final String region = Bytes.toString(entry.getKey());
    final HServerLoad.RegionLoad regionLoad = entry.getValue();
    long storeFileSize = regionLoad.getStorefileSizeMB();
    // other useful thing in regionLoad if you like
  }
}
```

Comment: ha ... I suppose I should change my display name - thanks for pointing that out :)

Comment: David, any advice on how to get RegionLoad object (or HRegion for that matter) already knowing HRegionInfo? I'm wrecking my brains trying to find out this seemingly straightforward connection via hbase api...

Comment: hi @IvanBalashov I am wondering were you able to get through this to get the size of the regions of a hbase table via api? I am having a similar situation and api is a maze right now.

Comment: @NikhilMulley Nope, sorry. But good luck to you! With HBase you'll need it! ;)

Comment: Yeah. there seems to be an api available for hbase but 0.96/0.98 as part of HBaseAdmin and I am using 0.94, so I am stuck until upgrade. Also the metrics exposed in 0.96 available make it easy for me to query the metrics system and check the regionsize, so thats another approach instead of api.

Answer (score 0):

What's wrong with the default [Load Balancer](http://hbase.apache.org/book/master.html#master.processes.loadbalancer)?

From the Wiki:

*The balancer is a periodic operation which is run on the master to redistribute regions on the cluster. It is configured via `hbase.balancer.period` and defaults to 300000 (5 minutes).*

If you really want to do it yourself you could indeed use the [Hadoop API](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/stable/api/index.html) and more specifally, the `FileStatus` class. This class acts as an interface to represent the client side information for a file.

Comment: actually Hbase's loadBalancer considers all the table for balancing, but I want to balance regions by individual table.

Comment: You might be interested in this then: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HBASE-3373