# How to get table region details from a RegionServer using HBase API?

Tags: hadoop, hbase

I'm new to the HBase API. I was wondering how I could get the region details of a particular table (say "T1") from a particular RegionServer (say RS1). I basically want to see the region size of a particular table in a region server.

I went through the docs for HRegionServer and HBaseAdmin, but I can't seem to find a way to get the details I need. I was assuming it would be pretty straightforward, but I guess it is not. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you talking about the HRegionInfo, if yes: https://hbase.apache.org/0.94/apidocs/org/apache/hadoop/hbase/HRegionInfo.html

Comment: one approach  at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14573466/get-hbase-region-size-via-api